# GraphQL API to get current user profile + get specific id user profile

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

In an app where you can view your own profile and view others' profiles:

Would you design this as 1 query with optional id arg?

```
profile: async (root, { id }, context) => {
  if (!context.user) throw unauthorized error

  if (id)
    profile = get profile for the passed in id
    return profile

  // if no id passed, get the current user instead
  profile = get profile for context.user.id
  return profile
}
```

or 2 separate queries, 1 for the currently logged in user, and 1 for others?

```
ownProfile: async (root, {}, context) => { get from context.user.id }
profile: async (root, { id }, context) => { get from id arg }  // otherProfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make both as although they both return the same type of object, they answer different questions.

GraphQL's strength is how expressive it is.

Of course, under the hood you can reuse the resolver logic.